# How to group child objects from one List in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

How do I take a List and then in a TreeView group them by their Class? I read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36451/Organizing-Heterogeneous-Data-on-a-WPF-TreeView.aspx), but it doesn't group the child objects, it just has the related properties in collections instead.

- Warehouse

  - Type A

    - Subtype 1
    - Subtype 2
  - Type B
  - Type C

If I have List that have all those types in there how do I show the grouping in a TreeView?

Before, I was manually adding them in, one TreeViewItem at a time.

```
List<Warehouse> myWarehouse = new List<Warehouse>();
TreeViewItem WarehouseNode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Warehouse" };
TreeViewItem TypeANode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Type A" };
foreach(SubtypeA type in myWarehouse) {
    TypeANode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = type.Name };
}
WarehouseNode.Items.Add(TypeANode);
etc. for Type B and Type C.
```

I was reading about [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=hierarchicaldatatemplate&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx&ei=U2DUUa2ZPMrC4AOauYHICg&usg=AFQjCNF5bqK83UYRUTvbAcCzXuz25NOAnA&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dmg) and it looks like this is how I want to go, using an [ItemTemplateSelector](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=itemtemplateselector&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemtemplateselector.aspx&ei=gGDUUfrMKLD64AP1jIHgCw&usg=AFQjCNHgGBXdRFGY7YkO7d2ScrHj3WA2zw&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dmg) to change the DataTemplate.

So, I started working with `HierarchicalDataTemplates` and came up with the below.

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Utility:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector" />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TypeCTemplate" DataType="{x:Type EntityType:TypeC}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}">
        <TextBlock Text="Type C"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TypeBTemplate" DataType="{x:Type EntityType:TypeB}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}">
        <TextBlock Text="Type B"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TypeATemplate" DataType="{x:Type EntityType:TypeA}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}">
        <TextBlock Text="Type A"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView Name="MyTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS}" 
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}">
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

I wrote a `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector {
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container) {
        MethodInfo mi = container.GetType().GetMethod("FindResource") as MethodInfo;
        if(mi != null) {
            string strItem = item.ToString().Split('.').Last();
            switch(item.ToString().Split('.').Last()) {
                case "Type A":
                    return mi.Invoke(container, new object[] { "TypeATemplate" }) as DataTemplate;
                case "Type B":
                    return mi.Invoke(container, new object[] { "TypeBTemplate" }) as DataTemplate;
                case "Type C":
                    return mi.Invoke(container, new object[] { "TypeCTemplate" }) as DataTemplate;
            }

            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

But now, when I look at the TreeView, it gives me this:

- Type B
- Type B
- Type B
- Type C
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Group your collection by setting [GroupDescriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.groupdescriptions.aspx) on its CollectionViewSource. You can do it in code by doing something like this:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(yourCollection).GroupDescriptions.Add(
new PropertyGroupDescription("PropertyName"));
```

Or you can do it in XAML by creating a CollectionViewSource explicitly.

```
<CollectionViewSource
    Source="{StaticResource yourCollection}"
    xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PropertyName"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Also check this out [enter link description here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/365#.UdRm2_lJM1I)

Comment: That groups by a `Property` and not by the object type itself.